# SortedSet is not removing some element from it

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, sortedset

SortedSet not removing some elements

I am trying to implement the A* pathfinding algorithm, everything is good so far except one this, SortedSet not removing some element.
It removes element, but some element is not removing and because of it the loop is going forever.

```cs
while (openNodes.Count > 0)
{
    currentPoint = openNodes.Min;
    currentPoint.SetIsSearched(true);
    openNodes.Remove(currentPoint);

    if (openNodes.Contains(currentPoint))
    {
        throw new Exception("MalFunctioning Detected...");
    }

    // Rest of the code 
}
```

My WayPoint class implemented IComparable interface

```
public int CompareTo(WayPoint other)
{
    // Index is the position in grid, grid contains the walkable and non walkable node, 
    // this class purpose is to hold data until shorted path found
    // If both points are at same location they are same

    if (other.Index.x == Index.x && other.Index.y == Index.y) return 0;
    else if (F < other.F || F == other.F && H < other.H) return -1;
    else return 1;
}
```

I'm sure nothing other than this is wrong with my code since, using **List** makes it run and finding path as expected.
I'm so frustrated by this, it's appreciable if anyone can explain to me what and why this happening.

Comment: You have strange comparison: `(F < other.F || F == other.F && H < other.H)`, what if `F == other.F && H == other.H` - why do you return `-1`, not `0`?

Comment: Have you tried to look into when it stops deleting elements. I recommend looking into that with a breakpoint, it could be possible that it always happens at a specific time. Maybe it stops deleting at the first try or at the last

Comment: without more code, we can't really run that to see what is happening, however - thoughts: what is `WayPoint`? is it a `class`? are you ever *changing* the values of `.Index`, `.F` or `.H` ? if so, you may have broken the tree - which, in the same way that a dictionary assumes hashing/equality doesn't change for keys, assumes that values don't suddenly re-order themselves; I would start by making `WayPoint` immutable (at least in terms of the things that it is sorted by), and see if that highlights a problem (i.e. it isn't finding the node because it is lost down a now-out-of-order branch)

Comment: if you say "but I need to change those values - that's literally the thing I'm trying to do", then: great - but you'll need to *remove* the value with the old values, and then *add* the value with the new values. That could be the same object before and after making the changes to the various fields, but IMO the easiest way to not get this wrong would be to make the type immutable, and simply `set.Remove(oldValue); set.Add(newValueWithTheChanges);` - I'd probably use a `readonly struct`, but that isn't critical.

Comment: side note: if two values have different X/Y but the same F/H, the sort order right now is broken: you'll get `x.Compare(y)==1` and `y.Compare(x)==1` - this breaks the expectations of comparers - it should be that if `x.Compare(y)>0` then `y.Compare(x)<0` - this *won't* cause the thing you're seeing, since `x.Compare(x)` must give the zero we want, since it'll have the same x/y as itself, but: it could cause *other* problems

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks man you save the day, My actual problem was lack of information. You are right the problem was that I was changing the G cost of WayPoint class (that directly affecting the F cost) and didn't understand the problem it causing, so now I first removed it from list and after changing the values adding it again. Also changed the comparison function to more senseful thing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, comparison must be *antisymmetric*, i.e. if

```
A > B
```

then

```
B < A
```

for all `A` and `B`. You break this rule; if `this` and `other` are not equal (i.e. `Index.x` or/and `Index.y` are not equal)

```
...

else if (F < other.F || F == other.F && H < other.H) 
  return -1;
else
  return 1; // <- when this.F == other.F && this.H == other.H
```

in case `this.F == other.F && H == other.H` `1` is returned and we have `this > other`;
if we *swap* `this` and `other` we expect `-1` to be returned, but we sill get `1`.

You, probably, want

```
public int CompareTo(WayPoint other) {
  // null is the smallest item 
  if (other is null)
    return 1;

  // Do you really want to compare y and y?
  if (other.Index.x == Index.x && other.Index.y == Index.y) 
    return 0;

  // Compare F's
  int compare = F.CompareTo(other.F);

  // If F's are not equal return the result
  if (compare != 0) 
    return compare;

  // Otherwise, compare H's
  return H.CompareTo(other.H);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was changing the value and not updating the set.
Solution is simple just remove the item before changing values that are affecting the sorting and add the item again to list, that sort the list again.

Also changed the comparison function too (according to Dmitry Bychenko)

```
        if (other == null) return 1;

        if (other.Index.x == Index.x && other.Index.y == Index.y) return 0;

        if (F != other.F)
            return F.CompareTo(other.F);
        else if (H != other.H)
            return H.CompareTo(other.H);
        else if (G != other.G)
            return G.CompareTo(other.G);
        else
            return 0;
```

Comment: This mix-and-match between [`operator==`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#reference-types-equality) and `CompareTo` is a recipe for disaster as the former only compares reference equality and does not perform any internal checking. Also you should account for `CompareTo` returning 0 - you should inspect next property in such case.

Comment: @orhtej2 Thanks to point it out, I will sure to look into it. Also in the case of CompareTo return 0, function should return 0 too, since it's not possible to have all F,H,G values and Index to be same until its a duplicate (or exactly same object), it's safe for me to return 0 in this case, AFAIK if it return 0 while adding it will ignore it and not add it (if I'm wrong, please correct me)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write a `CompareTo` function is to use the Waterfall pattern: each field is compared using `CompareTo`, if the result is not `0` then return it.

So `x` and `y` are compared separately, this way if *either* of them are different then you can have a guaranteed sort order.

You also have the comparison backwards: you need to compare *this* with *other*.

```cs
public int CompareTo(WayPoint? other)
{
    // Index is the position in grid, grid contains the walkable and non walkable node, 
    // this class purpose is to hold data until shorted path found
    // If both points are at same location they are same

    if (other == null)
        return 1;

    var cmp = Index.x.CompareTo(other.Index.x)
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;

    cmp = Index.y.CompareTo(other.Index.y);
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;

    cmp = F.CompareTo(other.F);
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;

    cmp = G.CompareTo(other.G);
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;

    cmp = H.CompareTo(other.H);
    return cmp;
}
```

You can refactor the `Index` comparison into its own `CompareTo` function as well.

---

If the `Index` by itself tells you that the values are equal, but does not sort them, then you can use this

```cs
public int CompareTo(WayPoint? other)
{
    // Index is the position in grid, grid contains the walkable and non walkable node, 
    // this class purpose is to hold data until shorted path found
    // If both points are at same location they are same

    if (other == null)
        return 1;

    if (Index.x == other.Index.x && Index.y == other.Index.y)
        return 0;

    cmp = F.CompareTo(other.F);
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;

    cmp = G.CompareTo(other.G);
    if (cmp != 0)
        return cmp;

    cmp = H.CompareTo(other.H);
    return cmp;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the conditions you provided is not what I need to do, since it's a part of A* algorithm and sorted Set used so I don't need to manually sorting things out, and this will return any value comparing Indexes too, I only need to return 0 if its the same object, and sort it only when F, H, G values are different.
But I understand what you mean surely.

Comment: But a `SortedSet` demands that the compare function returns in the correct order. You can still modify this to suit your purposes. See edits